# iPhone/iPad Dartboard, How Did They Do That?

Tags: iphone

http://gizmodo.com/5580399/ipadiphone-darts-make-this-whole-fanboy-lifestyle-worth-it

How did they do that?

Comment: Thank you for posting this... just made my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine the iPad is running some sort of server that the iPhone connects to.

The iPhone registers the orientation/gyro responses from its accelerometer as you 'throw' the dart, packages this up into a bit of readable data and sends this information to the server (on the iPad) which processes this and responds accordingly.

That's the way I see it being done anyway.